# How to make sort-by-type as default file/folder sorting in Explorer++

Tags: windows-10, file-management, sorting

I really like all the features of [explorer++](https://explorerplusplus.com/download). However, I can't figure out a way to sort files by type as default as supposed to by name. I have checked their [documentation](https://explorerplusplus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) but can't locate the information.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that such an option exists.

Given that this feature request was first raised in
[2009](https://explorerplusplus.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=221),
then again in
[2013](https://explorerplusplus.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=1082&p=4060&hilit=default+sort+order#p4060),
all in vain, it seems to me that your choices are:

1. Raise it again in the
   [Explorer++ forum](https://explorerplusplus.com/forum/)
2. Use
   [an alternative file manager](https://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-file-manager.htm).